# Trouble Installing Packages for Blender Python

Tags: python, import

I'm having issues installing certain packages in Blender 2.93's python on Windows. I also have Python (3.9.5) installed on my system, which might be causing the interference. I was able to get opencv installed with the following steps:

1. Go to the path where your blender python is stored: cd "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\python\bin"
2. Check that pip is working for Blender python: ./python.exe -m ensurepip
3. Install your packages: ./python.exe -m pip install opencv-contrib-python

This worked for opencv, but doesn't work for mediapipe. I have mediapipe installed on my system python and it works fine. But when I try to run it in Blender's text editor I get an error that a dependency `google` is not installed but it should be. What should I do? I'm trying to setup BlendyPose by the way, but hit this wall. https://github.com/zonkosoft/BlendyPose

Thank you for the help!

Comment: it may be worth reading: https://github.com/robertguetzkow/blender-python-examples/tree/master/add_ons/install_dependencies#installing-the-package and https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/commit/71e8c5c544e7476813399ccf05e3e9f4ee85b64d